# How to make Windows Subsystem for Linux use proxied connections?

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As in title, I want to make Ubuntu 20.04 LTS WSL use proxied connections; I am in China, behind the infamous Great Firewall of China, if that doesn't ring any bells, just Google it.

Fortunately I know how to bypass it freely(as in "free of charge"), currently I use Lantern, its http proxy port is 1053, I had set it to "manage system proxy" and "proxy all traffic", I had run these commands:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1:1053
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d "127.0.0.1:1053" /f
```

And made Lantern proxy PowerShell traffic in addition to browsers and downloaders.

Now, I enabled Windows Subsystem for Linux, installed wsl_update_x64.msi, installed Ubuntu 20.04, and ran this:

```
sudo apt update
```

And it downloads files from archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com with astonishingly slow speed: several (below 10)KB/s, my connection is 100mbps PPPoE(translates to 11.920928955078125MiB/s download speed), undoubtly it isn't being proxied, so how can I proxy its traffic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Never mind, I had just solved it, again, and found sometimes Google really can be useful, well, I said ***SOMETIMES***.

I just found this:
https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-apt-for-ubuntu-18-04/

I used these:

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:1053/";
:wq
```

(AND I closed Ubuntu)

Now its speed is much more resonable.

Comment: What about git clone, wget, curl, etc... I don't think they are proxied if you do this. Are they?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me too..

For other general HTTP access you can set proxy as follow

```
export http_proxy=<proxyUrl>:<proxyPort>
```

You can also have this in bash profile so that you do not have to set it each time.

Comment: This answer is the general solution for **http/https** connetion.
(even working for "$ kubectl krew update" )

Answer (score 1):

I am able to resolve this issue of my Python code by following code

```
export https_proxy=<proxyUrl>:<proxyPort> && export http_proxy=$https_proxy && no_proxy=.<domainUrl>,127.0.0.1,localhost
```

You can set this to your bash profile for future usage.