# No internet connection in WSL2 Ubuntu through px-proxy

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, wsl2, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Windows 10 machine that connects to internet via [px-proxy](https://github.com/genotrance/px) using localhost and port 1234 without login what works just fine; PowerShell & Co. can successfully connect to the internet.
Now I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS over WSL2 and from there I'm unable to connect to the internet.

I tried

- [using Google nameserver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67756837/4112892):

```
> more etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

- [exporting the proxy settings in `.bashrc`](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-proxy-settings#ftoc-heading-2) (also tried with port 4000):

```
> tail .bashrc
...
export http_proxy="123.456.78.9:1234";
export https_proxy="123.456.78.9:1234";
```

- [configuring `/etc/apt/apt.conf/proxy.conf`](https://medium.com/@astashkinav/configuring-a-proxy-for-ubuntu-wsl-d6ba9df63a41)  (also tried with port 4000):

```
> more /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
Acquire {
  HTTP::proxy "http://123.456.78.9:1234";
  HTTPS::proxy "http://123.456.78.9:1234";
}
```

- [add a port proxy to connect WSL2 and host as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-a-wsl-2-distribution-from-your-local-area-network-lan) or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1612914/how-to-make-windows-subsystem-for-linux-use-proxied-connections):

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=4000 connectaddress=123.456.78.9
```

and combinations of.
I made sure the IP of the host...

```
> ipconfig
...
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 123.456.78.9
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : abc.abc.abc.a
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

... matches those of WSL2 Ubuntu:

```
> ip route
default via 123.456.78.9 dev eth0
123.456.78.9/10 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src xyz.xyz.ba.b
```

Now I am lost with the various possibilities and not sure, if I am doing something obviously wrong here or if I am overlooking something. Thank you in advance for any hints! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uff figured it out, finally :)

So, to reach the internet through a proxy from a Ubuntu distro on WSL2:

First, catch the ip adress of the host machine:

```
> ipconfig
...
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : reddog.microsoft.com
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 987.654.32.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : xyz.xyz.xyz.z
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 11.111.111.1
```

- `etc/resolv.conf` remains as is
- Add the ip adress of your host machine and the port that the proxy runs on to .bashrc:

```
export http_proxy="987.654.32.1:1234"
export https_proxy="987.654.32.1:1234"
```

- Add the proxy and port to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf` as well:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://987.654.32.1:1234/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://987.654.32.1:1234/";
```

- and finally, add an appropriate rule to the Windows Firewall on port 1234 (else, WSL2 is unable to communicate with the proxy). **Be careful here!**

Answer (score 0):

in your `~/.profile` try

```
WINDOWS_IP=$(powershell.exe -Command '(Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)").IPAddress | Write-Host')
export http_proxy="http://${WINDOWS_IP}:3128"
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
```

check the port